# Que sistema o protocolo utilizan los operadores de telefonía para ofrecer acceso a redes sociales sin consumo de datos?

Tags: redes

En Colombia se hacen recargas de paquetes que incluyen redes sociales como facebook, whatsaap, y correo electrónico sin limite de datos, como hace el sistema para reconocer que es una aplicación de redes sociales para no afectar el saldo de datos del plan???

Comment: Es la primera vez que participo en este foro, como podria realizar la pregunta? no son opiniones, es un hecho que algunas aplicaciones como las de redes sociales no consumen los datos del plan, al menos en colombia.

Comment: @BetaM me gustaria saber como puede ser basada en opiniones esta pregunta en particular. y como seria amplia? la pregunta es como hace una empresa X para reconocer si un paquete de datos es de una app en particular como para no tomarlo en el calculo del gasto de gigas...

Comment: Si existieran implementaciones distintas, entonces seria como decir que hay distinto codigo para resolver un algoritmo... Puede que no haya una respuesta correcta en particular, pero seguro no esta basada en opiniones.. podria ser muy amplia, ponele.. pero tengamos cuidado con lo que le contamos a los nuevos usuarios... no borres nada, cada uno es libre de opinar como guste...

Answer (score 5):

Tu móvil usa una interfaz de comunicación (GPRS, EGPRS, UMTS, HSDPA, HSUP, LTE o NSA) con las antenas y que se conectan a la central de tu operadora móvil.
Las redes Móviles no dejan de ser un punto de entrada al igual que es el router de tu casa. Una vez que tu te conectas a la red de tu operadora te asignan un HOST (IP), NetMask y DNS entre otras cosas.

Una DNS (Domain Name System) se encarga de traducir cada petición a una dirección IP (dirección objetivo), por ejemplo http://youtube.com lo traduciría a 172.217.17.14.

Todo pasa por una direción IP, asi que si sabes cual es la dirección IP, se puede filtrar para reclamar un cargo o no en la tarifa.
Si te interesa el tema, [te recomiendo un vídeo](https://youtu.be/h2oFquv96O8)

Y si quieres comprobar por ti mismo, crea una red wifi con el portátil y abre wireshark (un analizador de red), navega y comprueba.

Un saludo